# Blogger Post Background Opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity, blogger

Alright, I cant think of a way to do this but on [My Blogger](http://maxandmead.theadventuresofaspy.com/) behind the post is a brownish tan background and I cant change the opacity, I can make it a solid color but not change the opacity. I as wondering if there is a CSS workaround for that. or any other workaround to make the opacity less see through so the text does not clash so hard with the dark liquid in the wine glass.

Any help is awesome, thanks
Maxthespy

Comment: You are looking for rgba. But: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `opacity: 0.5;`. Note that you'll also need `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` in order to deal with those pesky early IE versions ;)

**EDIT**:

Changing the opacity will change the entire opacity of the div, including its text contents. In order to use both a transparent `background-url` and have solid text, you'll need a bit of a hack CSS to actually use the background image in the `:after` of `post-outer`, and set it to appear in the same spot in the background:

```
.post-outer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  border: dotted 1px #ccb299;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.post-outer::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://resources.blogblog.com/blogblog/data/1kt/watermark/post_background_birds.png);
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I gave this a go and It looks like I need the post background to be less see through. I need to barely be able to see the wine glass

Comment: You can adjust the transparency level by changing the `opacity` value. `opacity: 0.5;` means 50% opacity. If you want it nearly invisible, you could drop it down to something like `opacity: 0.1;` (10% visibility). Don't forget to change the filter to handle early IE browsers as well. In that case it would be `filter: alpha(opacity=10)` :)

Comment: I went all the way to 1.0 and It wasnt dark enough, I changed the RGB color to: opacity: rgba(195,136,39,0.5);

This works ok, I think that It could be a little darker still but Its much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line for `.post-outer`

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(https://resources.blogblog.com/blogblog/data/1kt/watermark/post_background_birds.png) repeat scroll top left`
```

With an rgba background color, where the first 3 values are the RGB value for whatever color you want to use, and the last value is the opacity value. This is "white" (255,255,255) with 90% opacity.

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
```

Comment: that did something but not what I wanted, I wanted the opacity of that same color to be darker.

Comment: @CrowEcho The image they're using as the background is a white png with alpha transparency. It's the same exact thing I gave you, except I don't know what their transparency/opacity value is. I'm not sure what you mean by "opacity of that same color to be darker." Opacity isn't light or dark. Try changing the "0.9" in the thing I gave you to "0.5" or "0.3". If you're looking for a dark color, not a light one, you can use black by using `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` where "0.5" is the opacity value, which you can change to 0.1 (10% visible), 0.2 (20%), 0.3 (30%), etc.

Comment: That worked a little better but I still think the background could be darker, I added a dark brown and IT didnt seem to chage a whole lot. Ill try to find a sweet spot between color and opacity